# Need help with sql query, grouping and union/join?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a mysql table with 3 columns:

- **id** [int]
- **name** [varchar]
- **time** [timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]
- **flag** [boolean]

I am using a query like this to group the results by day:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name), DATE(time) as day FROM `table` GROUP BY day
```

That works fine, but what I really want to get `COUNT(DISTINCT name) WHERE FLAG = 0` and `COUNT(DISTINCT name) WHERE FLAG = 1` in the same query and group them by day.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to apply grouping first on flag then on day

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name), DATE(time) as day FROM `table` GROUP BY flag,day
```

Comment: I presume you'd also want to select the flag field so you can see which of the counts belongs to that field.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering that you want to create the result with a stored procedure or only a select query?

```
"date" 
"count number of flag = 1" 
"count number of flag =0"
```

You can

1. create 2 template tables and insert results from query "flag =1" and query of "flag = 0" into them
2. join 2 template tables on "date".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think this might help..
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name), DATE(time) as day FROM `table` GROUP BY day HAVING FLAG=0 and FLAG=1

Or you can manipulate this query as you want to group..